# Modal only shows last element of mapped array in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jsx

Right now im trying to render an elements respective contents if the user clicks on the button. As of right now since it is creating a modal for every element once i press a the button it opens up all of the modals, showing the last one.

I looked at previous questions regarding this and some assistance would be very appreciated.

For example, once i press on a button for that project card to view more about that project, it'll only show information for the last element of the array that is being mapped.

```
const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false)
 return (
   <>
  <Grid container
    direction="row"
    className="Project--Items" 
    xs={9} >
    {projects.map((project) => (
      <div key={project.id}className="Project--Card">
        <img src={project.image} className="Item--Main--Image"/>
        <div className="Card--Text">
          <p>{project.name}</p>
          <p>{project.description}</p>
        </div>
        <button onClick={() => setModalIsOpen(true)}>Open Modal</button>
        <Modal isOpen={modalIsOpen} onRequestClose={()=> setModalIsOpen(false)}>
          <h2>{project.name}</h2>
          <p>{project.description}</p>
          <div>
            <button onClick={() => setModalIsOpen(false)}>Close Modal</button>
          </div>
        </Modal>

      </div>
      
    ))}
  </Grid>

  </>
);
}
```

Comment: First of all, you need to declare the Modal component outside of the map function, so there is only one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false)
const [selectedProject, setSelectedProject] = useState(null);

const expandModal = (project) => {
    setSelectedProject(project);
    setModalIsOpen(true);
}

const closeModal = () => {
    setSelectedProject(null);
    setModalIsOpen(true);
}

 return (
  <Grid container
    direction="row"
    className="Project--Items" 
    xs={9} >
    {projects.map((project) => (
      <div key={project.id}className="Project--Card">
        <img src={project.image} className="Item--Main--Image"/>
        <div className="Card--Text">
          <p>{project.name}</p>
          <p>{project.description}</p>
        </div>
        <button onClick={() => expandModal(project)}>OpenModal</button>
      </div>
    ))}
    <Modal isOpen={modalIsOpen} onRequestClose={closeModal}>
      <h2>{selectedProject && selectedProject.name}</h2>
        <p>{selectedProject && selectedProject.description}</p>
        <div>
          <button onClick={closeModal}>Close Modal</button>
        </div>
    </Modal>
  </Grid>
);
}
```

Comment: Amazing! thank you both I see what was happening before.

Answer (score 0):

The structure is a bit shaky here. You should have a hidden Modale above all your content, and simply pass it some information. It will avoid rendering countless modals on the dom.

What about something like:

```js
function Modale ({isOpen, onClose, project}){
return isOpen && (
      <>
          <h2>{project.name}</h2>
          <p>{project.description}</p>
          <div>
            <button onClick={onClose}>Close Modal</button>
          </div>
        </>
}

function List (){
const [modalIsOpen, setModalIsOpen] = useState(false)
const [focusProject, setFocusProject] = useState(null)

const onOpenModale = (project) => {
  setModalIsOpen(true)
  setFocusProject(project)
}

const onCloseModale = () => {
  setModalIsOpen(false)
  setFocusProject(null)
}

 return (
   <>
   <Modale isOpen={modalIsOpen} onClose={onCloseModale} project={focusProject}/>
     <Grid container direction="row" className="Project--Items" xs={9} >
        {projects.map((project) => (
          <div key={project.id} className="Project--Card">
            <img src={project.image} className="Item--Main--Image"/>
            <div className="Card--Text">
            <p>{project.name}</p>
            <p>{project.description}</p>
            </div>
          <button onClick={()=> onOpenModale(project)}>Open Modal</button>
         </div>
       ))}
     </Grid>
  </>
);
}
```