# React is only passing the last object in my array to a component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I have a react component where I map through a list of clients and display each client in a card.

```
  return (
    <div className='VolunteerClientsTab'>
      {volunteerClients && volunteerClients.map((client) => (
        <React.Fragment key={client.id}>
          <div className='VolunteerClientsTab__card'>
            <Avatar style={{ alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: '.5rem' }}>{client.first_name[0]}{client.last_name[0]}</Avatar>
            <h2>{client.first_name} {client.last_name}</h2>
            <h4>Details</h4>
            <p><AiOutlineMail style={iconStyles} /> {client.email}</p>
            <p><AiOutlinePhone style={iconStyles} /> {formatPhoneNumber(client.contact_number)}</p>
            <h4 style={{ marginTop: '1rem' }}>Actions</h4>
            <p onClick={handleOpenClientNeedsModal} className='hover-underline'><BiDonateHeart style={iconStyles} />View Needs</p>
            <p className='hover-underline'><HiOutlineDocumentReport style={iconStyles} />Write Report</p>
            <p className='hover-underline'><FiVideo style={iconStyles} />Contact Client</p>
          </div>
          <ClientNeeds open={openClientNeedsModal} handleClose={handleCloseClientNeedsModal} client={client} />
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </div>
  )
};
```

**ClientNeeds** is a component that renders an MUI modal to display additional client information. I am passing it the **client** object within the loop but when I open the modal only the client of the last index in the volunteerClients array was passed to all the modal components. Does anyone have any idea why this is happening?

**ClientNeeds component**

```
import React from 'react';
import Box from '@mui/material/Box';
import Modal from '@mui/material/Modal';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

const style = {
  position: 'absolute',
  top: '50%',
  left: '50%',
  transform: 'translate(-50%, -50%)',
  width: 400,
  bgcolor: 'background.paper',
  border: '2px solid #000',
  boxShadow: 24,
  p: 4,
};

const ClientNeeds = ({ open, handleClose, client }) => {

  return (
    <div>
      <Modal
        open={open}
        onClose={handleClose}
        aria-labelledby="modal-modal-title"
        aria-describedby="modal-modal-description"
      >
        <Box sx={style}>
          <h2>{client.email}</h2>
        </Box>
      </Modal>
    </div>
  )
};

ClientNeeds.propTypes = {
  open: PropTypes.bool,
  handleClose: PropTypes.func,
  client: PropTypes.object
};

export default ClientNeeds;
```

**MY SOLUTION**

Passing the **client** `onClick` to an additional global state object and passing that state object to the modal,

```
  const [selectedClient, setSelectedClient] = useState(null)
```

also only rendering the **clientNeedsModal** is there is an object in that state.

```
    <div className='VolunteerClientsTab'>
      {volunteerClients && volunteerClients.map((client) => (
        <React.Fragment key={client.id}>
          <div className='VolunteerClientsTab__card'>
            <Avatar style={{ alignSelf: 'center', marginTop: '.5rem' }}>{client.first_name[0]}{client.last_name[0]}</Avatar>
            <h2>{client.first_name} {client.last_name}</h2>
            <h4>Details</h4>
            <p><AiOutlineMail style={iconStyles} /> {client.email}</p>
            <p><AiOutlinePhone style={iconStyles} /> {formatPhoneNumber(client.contact_number)}</p>
            <h4 style={{ marginTop: '1rem' }}>Actions</h4>
            <p onClick={() => handleOpenNeeds(client)} className='hover-underline'><BiDonateHeart style={iconStyles} />View Needs</p>
            <p className='hover-underline'><HiOutlineDocumentReport style={iconStyles} />Write Report</p>
            <p className='hover-underline'><FiVideo style={iconStyles} />Schedule Meeting</p>
          </div>
          {selectedClient ? (
            <ClientNeeds open={openClientNeedsModal} handleClose={handleCloseClientNeedsModal} client={selectedClient} />
          ) : null}

        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </div>
```

```
  const handleCloseClientNeedsModal = () => {
    setSelectedClient(null)
    setOpenClientNeedsModal(false);
  }

  const handleOpenNeeds = (client) => {
    setSelectedClient(client)
    handleOpenClientNeedsModal()
  }
```

This allows me to pass any individual object within my array to the modal component as originally desired

Comment: can you reproduce at least a simplified version in codesandbox if possible

Comment: try having modal component outside the map https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66532393/modal-only-shows-last-element-of-mapped-array-in-react

Comment: What does openClientNeedsModal do

Comment: You only have a single `openClientNeedsModal` value it looks like, so if that is set to `true` it looks like _all_ modals will open. I would guess that the last modal is stacked on top because it is lowest in the DOM.